# How do I get Python to starting reading a file on the first line?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read through a log that contains a list of files that caused errors, identify the filenames, and print the fullpath to those files. There is one file per line and it has particular formatting to delimit information of different types, so I am looking to stop reading at the first instance of a "." character in each line (none of the files have extensions). It works exactly as intended... except that it always begins at the second line of the error list and ends one past the last line, so it skips the first file. To me this seems like an indexing error, but I can't see what I've indexed incorrectly.

```
errorList = "path/to/listoferrors"
PART = ""
partCounter = 0
currentChar = ""

with open(errorList, "r") as file: #opens list of errors
    for line in file:              
        for char in line:          
            currentChar = file.read(1)
            if((currentChar != ".") and (partCounter == 0)): #check if we've reached the end of the PART
                PART = PART + currentChar
```

The above is the start of the code. It builds the filename character by character until it gets to the period. I'm fairly new to python, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get it to start on the first line of the file?

Comment: You're calling `file.read(1)` inside the loop. That will read the first character of the next line. And the next iteration will start after that.

Comment: That's hideously inefficient. String concatenation like that is creating a new string each time. Look into str.partition('.') as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

And Barmar is correct, you are already doing 'for char in line' -> char is your currentChar.

Comment: Why are you doing `currentChar = file.read(1)`? `char` is already the current character.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I appreciate the quick response. These are good points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in file:
```

reads the file line by line. So it reads the first line of the file on the first iteration.

Then when you do `currentChar = file.read(1)`, it starts reading from where the `for` loop left off, which is the beginning of the second line. That's why you're skipping the first line.

If you want to read until the first `.` in each line, use `line.index('.')` to find that position, and slice the line.

```
for line in file:
    dot = line.index('.')
    if dot != -1:
        part = line[:dot]
```